# how to identify corresponding html object using label using java

Tags: java, jsoup

I have html file and I have the label name now I need to identify the html object.
Can you please help me to identify the object.
I am using jsoup to parase, 
I could not attaching the screen shot,

The page has top row with label  below are html object

program, study,  study status, study manager    (all are labels and below html obj)

text box  dropdown, drop down, text box     (html objec)

Answer (score 0):

When working with HTML, it pays to be aware of the structure of the HTML elements, and not how they are rendered on-screen. In your case, you will need to find a way to identify the elements you seek *in the HTML code*, and and then use one of the `Document#getElement(s|)By(.+)` methods to find it.